# Spring Security Logout session is not invalidated

Tags: spring, session, spring-mvc, spring-security

I tried almost everything I could find on StackOverflow and elsewhere to make this working and this still does not work. I am using Spring Framework 4.1.6.RELEASE, Spring Security 4.0.0.RELEASE. I configured the namespace logout tag and the only way I am able to invalidate a session is by doing it programmatically in my controller with a HttpSession.invalidate() call.

When requesting a logout, I am redirected to the appropriate page, however the session is never invalidated and the JSESSIONID is not deleted. And NO this is not a cache effect. I tried all the fine cache suggestions and I am having @PreAuthorize annotations and my user MUST BE authenticated to call them and it can call them even if it logs out. The only way to invalidate the session is to enter a bad username/password in the login panel where I am redirected and refused authentication. At this point, the session is destroyed.

I am out of ideas and hints.

Here is my security-applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<b:beans xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd">

<!-- -->
<b:bean id="securityExpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler" >
    <b:property name="defaultRolePrefix" value="ROLE_" />
</b:bean>
<b:bean id="preInvocationAdvice" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice" >
    <b:property name="expressionHandler" ref="securityExpressionHandler" />
</b:bean>
<b:bean id="postInvocationAdvice" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedPostInvocationAdvice" >
    <b:constructor-arg ref="securityExpressionHandler" />
</b:bean>
<b:bean id="myRoleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
    <b:property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_" />
</b:bean>
<!-- -->

<!-- Configuration de l'accès et du formulaire -->
<!-- Permettre l'accès libre aux feuilles de style, polices et images -->
<http pattern='/resources/css/**' security="none" />
<http pattern='/resources/fonts/**' security="none" />
<http pattern='/resources/images/**' security="none" />
<http pattern='/resources/js/**' security="none" />

<http use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">

    <!-- Limitation à une seule session utilisateur concurrente -->
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/identite?session_invalide=1"
        session-authentication-error-url="/identite?identite_err=1">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"
            expired-url="/identite?expiree=1" />
    </session-management>

    <!-- Définitions pour le formulaire de la page JSP d'identification -->
    <form-login login-page="/identite" login-processing-url="/identite.proc" default-target-url="/" always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/identite?identite_err=1" username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />
    <csrf disabled="false" />

    <logout logout-url="/deconnexion"
        logout-success-url="/identite?termine=1"
        delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true"
         />

    <!-- Utiliser un canal chiffré pour les échanges -->
    <intercept-url requires-channel="https" pattern="/identite*" access="permitAll()" />
    <intercept-url requires-channel="https" pattern="/deconnexion*" access="permitAll()" />
    <intercept-url requires-channel="https" pattern="/logout*" access="permitAll()" />
    <intercept-url requires-channel="https" pattern="/action*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_SUPPORT')" />
    <intercept-url requires-channel="https" pattern="/causes*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url requires-channel="https" pattern="/telechargement*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url requires-channel="https" pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/erreur403" />
</http>

<!-- Fournisseurs d'identité pour le formulaire -->
<authentication-manager erase-credentials="true">
    <authentication-provider ref="monFournisseurAD" />
</authentication-manager>
<b:bean id="grantedAuthoritiesMapper" class="com.company.gisti.securite.ad.ActiveDirectoryGrantedAuthoritiesMapper">
    <b:description>Cette fève (bean) met en place la correspondance entre les groupes AD/LDAP et les rôles au niveau applicatif.</b:description>
    <b:property name="groupesAdministrateur">
        <b:description>Ensemble de noms de groupes dans AD/LDAP indiquant que l'usager a un rôle d'administrateur pour cette application.</b:description>
        <b:set value-type="java.lang.String">
            <b:value>SecRole-Support-DDMI</b:value>
        </b:set>
    </b:property>
    <b:property name="groupesSupport">
        <b:description>Ensemble de noms de groupes dans AD/LDAP indiquant que l'usager a un rôle d'usager de support pour cette application.</b:description>
        <b:set value-type="java.lang.String">
            <b:value>SecRole-Support-HpSM</b:value>
            <b:value>SecRole-AdminSystemeHPUCMDB</b:value>
        </b:set>
    </b:property>
    <b:property name="groupesUsager">
        <b:description>Ensemble de noms de groupes dans AD/LDAP indiquant que l'usager a un rôle d'utilisateur simple pour cette application. </b:description>
        <b:set value-type="java.lang.String">
            <b:value>SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM</b:value>
        </b:set>
    </b:property>
</b:bean>

<!-- Identification par Active Directory -->
<b:bean id="monFournisseurAD" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <b:constructor-arg value="campus.company.com" />                <!-- userPrincipalName de la forme username@campus... -->
    <b:constructor-arg value="ldap://fsapps.company.uni:389/" />    <!-- Comment rejoindre le serveur -->
    <b:constructor-arg value="dc=fsapps,dc=company,dc=uni" />   <!-- baseObject -->
    <b:property name="searchFilter" value="(&amp;(userPrincipalName={0})(objectClass=user))" />
    <b:property name="userDetailsContextMapper">
        <b:bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.InetOrgPersonContextMapper" />
    </b:property>
    <b:property name="authoritiesMapper" ref="grantedAuthoritiesMapper" />
    <b:property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true" />
</b:bean>

<b:bean id="securityContextPersistenceFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter" />
<b:bean id="myDeconnexionHandler" class="com.company.gisti.web.app.DeconnexionHandler" />

</b:beans>
```

And here is my mvc-applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled" />
<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/theme_desjardins/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven /><mvc:interceptors>
<mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"></property>
        <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"></property>
        <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"></property>
        <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"></property></bean>
</mvc:interceptor></mvc:interceptors>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.gisti.web.app" />

</beans>
```

In my security xml file, there is a logout success handler defined, I do not use it in this configuration, but I tried with one and it was never called. I can probably implement a logoutHandler, but at this point it is almost equivalent to invalidate the session as I am doing from the servlet controller.

---

**Update 2015-04-23 11:06:00 EDT**

My problem was the logout URL was access via the GET method instead of POST as it should have been givin the CSRF protection is enabled. I corrected that part and the session is now properly invalidated. The only thing that still not work is the redirection to the login page. BTW, my logout URL is /deconnexion and my login URL is /identite. So, the session is actually invalidated and am kept on the same page but background processes are not longer authorized as expected since they are no longer authentified to access the server. I need to click on an unauthorized URL to finally get the page refreshed due to an AccessDeniedException. In the following log, I am not giving the complete result from clicking on such URL, the URL is /causes in the log. It will lead to an exception which will then redirect to the login page. The first two lines in the log refer to the login and page loading completed successfully, then the logout is initiated.

```
2015-04-23 11:01:40,040 DEBUG (o.s.w.s.FrameworkServlet.processRequest) [http-8443-1] Successfully completed request MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:40,040 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter) [http-8443-1] Chain processed normally MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:40,040 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter) [http-8443-1] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,020 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-2] Checking match of request : '/deconnexion'; against '/resources/css/**' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,020 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-2] Checking match of request : '/deconnexion'; against '/resources/fonts/**' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,020 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-2] Checking match of request : '/deconnexion'; against '/resources/images/**' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,020 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-2] Checking match of request : '/deconnexion'; against '/resources/js/**' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,020 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-2] /deconnexion at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ChannelProcessingFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,020 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-2] Checking match of request : '/deconnexion'; against '/identite*' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,020 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-2] Checking match of request : '/deconnexion'; against '/deconnexion*' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,020 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.a.c.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter) [http-8443-2] Request: FilterInvocation: URL: /deconnexion; ConfigAttributes: [REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL] MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,020 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-2] /deconnexion at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,020 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession) [http-8443-2] Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@49e898d4: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@49e898d4: Principal: org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.InetOrgPerson@644dcdae: Dn: CN=MYUSERNAME,OU=Utilisateurs,DC=fsapps,DC=company,DC=uni; Username: myusername; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; CredentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: SecRole-Support-DDMI, SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffe3f86: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 783C021534873EBDFCCD914F8B7F1C8C; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER, ROLE_SUPPORT' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,020 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-2] /deconnexion at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ConcurrentSessionFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,020 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-2] /deconnexion at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,035 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-2] /deconnexion at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,035 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-2] /deconnexion at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,035 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-2] Checking match of request : '/deconnexion'; against '/deconnexion' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,035 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.a.l.LogoutFilter.doFilter) [http-8443-2] Logging out user 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@49e898d4: Principal: org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.InetOrgPerson@644dcdae: Dn: CN=MYUSERNAME,OU=Utilisateurs,DC=fsapps,DC=company,DC=uni; Username: myusername; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; CredentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: SecRole-Support-DDMI, SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffe3f86: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 783C021534873EBDFCCD914F8B7F1C8C; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER, ROLE_SUPPORT' and transferring to logout destination MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,035 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.a.l.SecurityContextLogoutHandler.logout) [http-8443-2] Invalidating session: 444589E454C7CDF3C9DBFC62E8CA0541 MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,035 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionEventPublisher.sessionDestroyed) [http-8443-2] Publishing event: org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionDestroyedEvent[source=org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@565f0e7d] MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,035 DEBUG (o.s.s.c.s.SessionRegistryImpl.removeSessionInformation) [http-8443-2] Removing session 444589E454C7CDF3C9DBFC62E8CA0541 from principal's set of registered sessions MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,035 DEBUG (o.s.s.c.s.SessionRegistryImpl.removeSessionInformation) [http-8443-2] Removing principal org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.InetOrgPerson@644dcdae: Dn: CN=MYUSERNAME,OU=Utilisateurs,DC=fsapps,DC=company,DC=uni; Username: myusername; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; CredentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: SecRole-Support-DDMI, SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM from registry MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,035 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.a.AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.determineTargetUrl) [http-8443-2] Using default Url: /identite MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,035 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.DefaultRedirectStrategy.sendRedirect) [http-8443-2] Redirecting to '/CaissesDispo/identite' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,035 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper.saveContext) [http-8443-2] SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession. MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,035 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter) [http-8443-2] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,035 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-2] Checking match of request : '/identite'; against '/resources/css/**' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,035 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-2] Checking match of request : '/identite'; against '/resources/fonts/**' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,035 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-2] Checking match of request : '/identite'; against '/resources/images/**' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,035 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-2] Checking match of request : '/identite'; against '/resources/js/**' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,035 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-2] /identite at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ChannelProcessingFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,035 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-2] Checking match of request : '/identite'; against '/identite*' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,035 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.a.c.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter) [http-8443-2] Request: FilterInvocation: URL: /identite; ConfigAttributes: [REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL] MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,035 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-2] /identite at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,035 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession) [http-8443-2] No HttpSession currently exists MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,035 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.loadContext) [http-8443-2] No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created. MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,051 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-2] /identite at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ConcurrentSessionFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,051 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-2] /identite at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-2] /identite at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-2] /identite at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-2] Request 'GET /identite' doesn't match 'POST /deconnexion MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-2] /identite at position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-2] Request 'GET /identite' doesn't match 'POST /identite.proc MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-2] /identite at position 8 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-2] /identite at position 9 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-2] /identite at position 10 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter) [http-8443-2] Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-2] /identite at position 11 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-2] /identite at position 12 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-2] /identite at position 13 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-2] Checking match of request : '/identite'; against '/identite*' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.s.a.i.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation) [http-8443-2] Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /identite; Attributes: [permitAll()] MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.s.a.i.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.authenticateIfRequired) [http-8443-2] Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.s.a.v.AffirmativeBased.decide) [http-8443-2] Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@514ade37, returned: 1 MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.s.a.i.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation) [http-8443-2] Authorization successful MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.s.a.i.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation) [http-8443-2] RunAsManager did not change Authentication object MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-2] /identite reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet.doService) [http-8443-2] DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher' processing GET request for [/CaissesDispo/identite] MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.w.s.h.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal) [http-8443-2] Looking up handler method for path /identite MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.w.s.h.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal) [http-8443-2] Returning handler method [public java.lang.String com.company.gisti.web.app.ControleurIdentite.handleIdentiteJsp()] MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.b.f.s.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean) [http-8443-2] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'controleurIdentite' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch) [http-8443-2] Last-Modified value for [/CaissesDispo/identite] is: -1 MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.w.s.m.WebContentInterceptor.preHandle) [http-8443-2] Looking up cache seconds for [/identite] MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.w.s.m.WebContentInterceptor.preHandle) [http-8443-2] Applying default cache seconds to [/identite] MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 INFO (c.d.g.w.c.ControleurIdentite.handleIdentiteJsp) [http-8443-2] ************************* >>>>>>> Redirige vers identite <<<<<<<<<<<<< *************** MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet.render) [http-8443-2] Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'identite'; URL [/WEB-INF/pages/identite.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.b.f.s.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean) [http-8443-2] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'requestDataValueProcessor' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.w.s.v.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel) [http-8443-2] Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/pages/identite.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'identite' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionEventPublisher.sessionCreated) [http-8443-2] Publishing event: org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionCreatedEvent[source=org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@27573872] MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.b.f.s.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean) [http-8443-2] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler#0' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.b.f.s.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean) [http-8443-2] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'securityExpressionHandler' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.b.f.s.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean) [http-8443-2] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.b.f.s.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean) [http-8443-2] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler#0' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.b.f.s.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean) [http-8443-2] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'securityExpressionHandler' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,052 DEBUG (o.s.b.f.s.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean) [http-8443-2] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,083 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper.saveContext) [http-8443-2] SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession. MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,083 DEBUG (o.s.w.s.FrameworkServlet.processRequest) [http-8443-2] Successfully completed request MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,083 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter) [http-8443-2] Chain processed normally MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:43,083 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter) [http-8443-2] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:45,907 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-2] Checking match of request : '/causes'; against '/resources/css/**' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:45,907 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-2] Checking match of request : '/causes'; against '/resources/fonts/**' MDC{}
2015-04-23 11:01:45,907 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-2] Checking match of request : '/causes'; against '/resources/images/**' MDC{}
```

---

**Update 2015-04-23 14:37:00 SOLVED**

My problem is solved. Since I sent via ajax a POST to logout, I received the url where I am supposed to point my browser from my success logout handler. I have to manually point the browser to this location from my javascript with the window.location.href = new_url.

Comment: You need to do a POST to logout if csrf is enabled. Are you?

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I forgot enabling csrf would have consequences on the logout code. I am still having a problem. I replaced my <a href="/logout"></a> link by an ajax call, the logout completes gracefully, however I am not redirected on the indicated page after successful logout.

Instead, I stay on the same page and I have to click an unauthorized page on my menu to finally get to the expected page. The logs are very dense but basically, I can see a redirection which doesn't trigger anything in the browser until I click something that will lead to an access denied exception.

Comment: I am adding in my original post the related part of my log since I am limited in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering so you can close your question.

If you're using Spring Security's CSRF protection, you must POST to log out (though this is configurable I believe).

Can you do the logout POST with Javascript but non-AJAX? Like:

```
<!-- anywhere in your document: -->
<form:form action="deconnexion" id="logoutForm">
  <!-- csrf hidden input included automagically -->
</form:form>

<!-- in your menu: -->
<a href="#" onclick="document.forms.namedItem('logoutForm').submit()">Log out</a>
```

Comment: I did use AJAX because I needed to perform the action from a dropdown menu and couldn't insert a form there. I am including the javascript code with the AJAX request in my original post. As well as two screenshots showing the headers from the Firebug interface in my browser where you can see the target URL is actually received but no action is performed by the browser unless I explicitly do a window.location.href with the URL I am getting from the server.

Comment: Great tip Neil. Thanks very much. I was unaware of the Spring tag libraries. I have too many to handle right now to look at it more carefully. It works nicely, much more simple as well and cleaner code.

Answer (score 1):

---

**Update 2015-04-23 14:37:00 SOLVED**

My problem is solved. Since I sent via ajax a POST to logout, I received the url where I am supposed to point my browser from my success logout handler. I have to manually point the browser to this location from my javascript with the window.location.href = new_url.

---

**Update 2015-04-23 15:55:00 follow up**

*Note: I have to put this into a separated answer since I reached the limit of characters in a single post.*

Here is a snippet of my javascript code to post via ajax requesting the logout:

```
    $('#deconnexion').click(function(event) {
        // Envoyer la requête
        var csrfToken = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
        var csrfHeader = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
        var csrf_header = { };
        csrf_header[csrfHeader] = csrfToken;
        $.ajax({
            headers: csrf_header,
            url: 'deconnexion',
            processData: false,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "text/xml",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            /* */
                console.log("Etat rapporté: " + xhr.status);
                console.log("Données: " + data);
                console.log("Etat description: " + textStatus);
                console.log("reponseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                console.log("URL redirection: " + xhr.getResponseHeader("Location"));
            /*  */
                //window.location.href = xhr.getResponseHeader("Location");
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
            /*
                console.log("Etat rapporté: " + xhr.status);
                console.log("Erreur description: " + thrownError);
                console.log("Etat description: " + textStatus);
                console.log("reponseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                */
                window.location.href = xhr.getResponseHeader("Location");
            }
        });
    });
```

I haven't yet tested the error conditions. In the script the window.location.href is commented for the test.

Here are the screenshots:

[image: logout headers in firebug]
[image: answer to the logout request]

If there is something that can be done to let the browser and AJAX do the job, I am interested to know how I can do this.