# How to fully logout? Spring Security

Tags: spring, security, logout

How can I fully logout? I have in my xml file:

```
<security:logout logout-url="/logoutMe" />
```

And when I enter the /logoutMe url I am not logged out - on my controller I added:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()
```

And added the name to ModelAndView and display on my page, and there is still my username, not anonymousUser as before logging in.

How to logout totally?
I've also tried to create my own LogoutSuccessHandler implementation with:

```
SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
```

but.. it doesnt seem to work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring Security Logout session is not invalidated \[SOLVED\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29811266/spring-security-logout-session-is-not-invalidated-solved)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a method which Spring security calls by default on logout(from SecurityContextLogoutHandler class):

```
public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
    Assert.notNull(request, "HttpServletRequest required");
    if (invalidateHttpSession) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            logger.debug("Invalidating session: " + session.getId());
            session.invalidate();
        }
    }

    if(clearAuthentication) {
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        context.setAuthentication(null);
    }

    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
}
```

have you tried to use default, provided by spring security logout url `/logout`? Or you have to customize some things?

Comment: I have tried to use just simple /logout but I remain logged in. It looks like /logout didn't work. Maybe should I register some logout filters or so? If I dont use .clearContext() manually, nothing happens. /logout option seems to be.. disabled? calling it does nothing

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108585/spring-security-java-config-not-generating-logout-url /logout needs POST instead GET